# Flutter Futurebuilder gets modified

Tags: list, flutter, dart, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a Futurebuilder that fetches data from an Api.
I am assigning its data to a list;

```
List<TicketModel> ticketList = [];`
ticketList = snapshot.data;
```

Now the weird thing is, snapshot.data and ticketList should be independent right?

However if I remove data from the List e.g I remove every Object that has the price 1 the snapshot.data modifies too(Has same data as list now).

Why is that so?

The Futurebuilder is in a Modal bottom sheet if that's necessary

```
void main() {
  List<String> listofAllTickets =[];
  listofAllTickets = ["ticket eins","ticket zwei", "ticket drei"];
  List<String> listOfAllTicketsSecond = listofAllTickets;
  listOfAllTicketsSecond.removeWhere((element) => element == "ticket eins");
  print(listofAllTickets);
  print(listOfAllTicketsSecond);
}
```

Comment: Because you're not copying the contents of snapshot.data, you're copying the reference to its list, and assigning your list to point to it. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently, there is no `FutureBuilder` in your question.

Comment: @Jeppe you are right thanks thats exactly the problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a futurebuilder and connect ticketlist to it.  the futurebuilder will generate a snapshot in its callback function.  you can not access the snapshot outside of the futurebuilder.

I prefer using Bloc and streambuilder.  Streambuilder events occur when change occurs on the notification stream.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jeppe posted in the comments what I did **before** was that:

```
void main() {
  List<String> listofAllTickets =[];
  listofAllTickets = ["ticket eins","ticket zwei", "ticket drei"];
  List<String> listOfAllTicketsSecond = listofAllTickets;
  listOfAllTicketsSecond.removeWhere((element) => element == "ticket eins");
  print(listofAllTickets);
  print(listOfAllTicketsSecond);
}
```

the right solution would be doing this:

```
void main() {
  List listofAllTickets = ["ticket eins","ticket zwei", "ticket drei"];
  List listOfAllTicketsSecond = [];
  listOfAllTicketsSecond = List.from(listofAllTickets);
  listOfAllTicketsSecond.removeWhere((element) => element == "ticket eins");
  print(listofAllTickets);
  print(listOfAllTicketsSecond);
}
```

In Example two I am copying the data instead of referencing the list.